# How to arrange buttons programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get the control arrows in the standard D-Pad orientation centered and underneath the video stream but this is the best I've been able to do so far based on what I believe should be the correct code. Notice that the up and down arrows are in the correct location but the Left arrow doesn't show and the Right arrow is on the left. Either I'm not understanding something correctly or there is something affecting the arrangement of the arrows that I'm not catching.

```
   RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    setContentView(rl, relativeLayoutParams);

    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    rl.addView(mv);

    Button panLeft = new Button(this);
    panLeft.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_left);
    int panLeftID = View.generateViewId();
    panLeft.setId(panLeftID);

    Button panRight = new Button(this);
    panRight.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_right);
    int panRightID = View.generateViewId();
    panRight.setId(panRightID);

    Button tiltUp = new Button(this);
    tiltUp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
    int tiltUpID = View.generateViewId();
    tiltUp.setId(tiltUpID);

    Button tiltDown = new Button(this);
    tiltDown.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
    int tiltDownID = View.generateViewId();
    tiltDown.setId(tiltDownID);

    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rl.addView(tiltDown, relativeLayoutParams);

    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, tiltUpID);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rl.addView(panLeft, relativeLayoutParams);

    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tiltDownID);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    rl.addView(panRight, relativeLayoutParams);

    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, tiltDownID);
    relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rl.addView(tiltUp, relativeLayoutParams);
```

And here is what it looks like:
http://s23.postimg.org/otbyon2a3/screenie.png

Comment: What are the ID's you're setting for the Views and are they both distinct and > 0?

Comment: I'm just using the methods for each view like so:  
    int panRightID = View.generateViewId();
    panRight.setId(panRightID);

I'm assuming the methods are creating valid IDs.

Comment: Side note: Is there a tutorial for formatting in these comments?

Comment: Well I can tell you that when you try to add panLeft tiltUp is not added to the view so it can't be placed to the left of anything.

Comment: I'd also do all of this in XML, your approach feels awkward and more complicated that it needs to be IMO.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I've tried different combinations of ordering including adding all the buttons first and it didn't seem to matter. Also, the reason I can't use an XML is because the video stream is added programmatically and when it loads it overwrites anything that is added before it. So, the buttons in the XML would appear for a split second until the video container appears. I haven't found a way around this yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a grid layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/dpad_grid"
    >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Up"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Down"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

</GridLayout>
```

To echo @Dave S you should really use layouts for something like this.

Comment: I really wish I could, read my explanation above as to why I can't right now.

Comment: You could probably generate this programmatically without too much hassle. Our you could post your video stream code and we could have a look.

Comment: can we look at this via email? I can't post the code here because it is too long.

Comment: This layout worked for me when I also used the layoutInflater example found here: https://inphamousdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/first-development-blog-post/

Thank you!